# How to edit ELF by adding custom sections and symbols

Tags: python, c, elf

I want to take an elf file and then based on the content add a section with data and add symbols.  Using objcopy --add-section I can add a section with the content that I would like. I cannot figure out how to add a symbol.

Regardless, I would prefer not run a series of programs in order to do what I want but rather do it natively in c or python. In pyelftools I can view an elf, but I cannot figure out how to edit and elf.

How can I add custom sections and symbols in Python or C?

Comment: I know you can read ELF files using elf linux struct (http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man5/elf.5.html). I think it's possible to edit ELF symbols since you are moving in the elf files using pointers arithmetics, but you'll have to pad the ELF content

Comment: Not sure what you mean "add a symbol". As I recall, `objcopy` already does that, and you can reference in C or C++ as `extern char _binary_foo_txt_start[]`, `_end[]`, `_size[]` where `foo_txt` is the file you copied (e.g. `foo.txt`) (or `dlopen` + `dlsym`, etc.).

Comment: @FireLancer  , As I wrote, I can use objcopy to add custom symbols. I would however prefer to use a library that way I could more conveniently do it multiple times along with doing a set of other logic

Comment: is `libelf` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Ctx it looks like that would be good. I found it really hard to find a manual the only thing I found was an example that creates an elf here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/elftoolchain/ example number 5

Comment: is there a way to mark this as solved?

Comment: Yes, you can accept any of the given answers, or if they don't cover your solution, you can write one yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

ELF has nothing to do with the symbols stored in it by programs.  It is just a format to encode everything.  Symbols are generated normally by compilers, like the C compiler, fortran compiler or an assembler, while sections are fixed by the programming language (e.g. the C compiler only uses a limited number of sections, depending on the kind of data you are using in your programs).  Some compilers have extensions to associate a variable to a section, so the linke will consider it special in some way.  The compiler/assembler generates a symbol table in order for the linker to be able to use it to resolve dependencies.

If you want to add symbols to your program, the easiest way it to create an assembler module with the sections and symbols you want to add to the executable, then assemble it and link to the final executable.

Read about `ld(1)` program (the linker), and how it uses the link scripts (special hidden files that direct the linker on how to organize the sections in the different modules at link time) to handle the sections in an object file.  ELF is just a format.  If you use a link script and the help of the assembler, you'll be able to add any section you want or modify the normal memory map that programs use to have.

Answer (score 0):

To add a symbol to an ELF file you can use `objcopy --add-symbol` (how logical!).

> `--add-symbol name=[section:]value[,flags]`
>
> Add a new symbol named name while copying the file. This option may be specified multiple times. If the section is given, the symbol will be associated with and relative to that section, otherwise it will be an ABS symbol. Specifying an undefined section will result in a fatal error. There is no check for the value, it will be taken as specified. Symbol flags can be specified and not all flags will be meaningful for all object file formats. By default, the symbol will be global. The special flag ’before=othersym’ will insert the new symbol in front of the specified othersym, otherwise the symbol(s) will be added at the end of the symbol table in the order they appear.

For example:

```
❯ file test
test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=b41a48662a58bb74c584e5208bea0d3c8452695d, not stripped

❯ objcopy --add-symbol mysym=5 test test2

❯ nm test | grep mysym

❯ nm test2 | grep mysym
0000000000000005 A mysym
```

You can add absolute symbols and section-relative symbols as described. The `flags` can be used to set the symbol flags.

The [LLVM version of objcopy](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-objcopy.html) has a better description:

> `--add-symbol <name>=[<section>:]<value>[,<flags>]`
>
> Add a new symbol called  to the output symbol table, in the section named , with value . If  is not
> specified, the symbol is added as an absolute symbol. The 
> affect the symbol properties. Accepted values are:
>
> ```
> global = the symbol will have global binding.
> local = the symbol will have local binding.
> weak = the symbol will have weak binding.
> default = the symbol will have default visibility.
> hidden = the symbol will have hidden visibility.
> protected = the symbol will have protected visibility.
> file = the symbol will be an STT_FILE symbol.
> section = the symbol will be an STT_SECTION symbol.
> object = the symbol will be an STT_OBJECT symbol.
> function = the symbol will be an STT_FUNC symbol.
> indirect-function = the symbol will be an STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol.
> ```
>
> Additionally, the following flags are accepted but ignored: debug, constructor, warning, indirect, synthetic, unique-object, before.
>
> Can be specified multiple times to add multiple symbols.

Flags are comma separated.